# express router with id

Tags: node.js, express

I know I can do this in Express:

```
app.use('/:id', function (req, res){ // or app.get
    console.log('Test param: ' + req.params.id); // "Test param: foo"
});
```

to get my url parameter.

When I try to use a *router* logic I did:

**index.js**

```
var sites = require('./routes/sites');
app.use('/:id', sites);
```

**routes/sites.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id); // logs "undefined"
    // etc ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

this logic does not work, I get `{}` in the shell command, `undefined` for `req.params.id`.

Any idea where my logic is wrong?

Comment: How does it log `undefined` if you get a 404 at the same time?

Comment: @FaureHu hmm you're right, I do not get a 404. I did get that when I tried `router.get('/':id`  trying to debug the problem. I just get `undefined` for `req.params.id`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't work, because that's just not how express interacts with its `Router`s. The reason you're not seeing `id` inside your router, is because `:id` was not declared within its scope. You'd need to do something like

```
app.use('/', sites);
```

and in your router

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id); 
    // etc ...
});

module.exports = router;
```

Additionally you can try playing around with `app.param()` see docs for examples http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param

Comment: Yuri, thank you for checking this out. In that case do I need to have multiple `app.use('/', ` (calling root folder) to each subroute in different modules? and then in the module using `app.get`?

Comment: The way most people use routers, is that you specify the subpath, so for instance `app.use('/users', userRouter)`

Comment: I understand that, the issue here is when I use a `/:id` param directly from the root. Thank you for clearifying this for me. `+1`

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to do this in index.js and routes.js -

```
app.use('/:id', function (req, res){ // or app.get
    console.log('Test param: ' + req.params.id); // "Test param: foo"
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id); // logs "undefined"
    // etc ...
});
```

"id" is not defined there because that's how express works with routers, it just matches the routes matching with the specified prefix in app.use() method. For that, you can try using -

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
```

Now it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works now.

You can do something like

```
app.use('/:id/transactions', require('./routes/transactions'));
```

In the main file, and then add `{mergeParams:true}` to Router options in the controller file.

```
const router = require('express').Router({mergeParams:true});
```

So here you will be able to get the id that was set in base Route.

```
// localhost:5000/:id/transactions/
router.get('/',(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
}
```

Found here:
http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param

Answer (score 0):

In your file router/sites.js, add an option to express router:

```
const router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});
```

Now you have access to id in sites.js file.